# Firestore cloud functions Comment Counter: How to fix "Object is possibly undefined"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**Requested behaviour:** 
I would like to create a cloud function in typescript which gets executed every time a document gets added to a comments subcollection of a posts collection.
The execution should increase a counter on the parent document by one.

**Current State** 
The cloud function gets executed every time I create a document if I replace the "get promise" by a console.log() statement.

**issue** 
It does not execute the update part. Instead, it throws an error:
`Object is possibly 'undefined'`

**solution approaches** 
I had a similar issue at a different cloud function and used an if statement to solve it. However, I do not understand how to apply it here.

> How can I fix this issue? Do I have to use an if statement?

**My cloud function** 
[image]
**code if you want to copy it**

```js
export const createSubCollTrigger = 
functions.firestore.document('posts/{postID}/comments/{commentID}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    admin.firestore().doc('posts/{postID}').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.data()
        return admin.firestore().doc('posts/{postID}').update({postCommentsTot: data.postCommentsTot + 1});  
    })

    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        return
    })
})
```

**

Comment: Thanks for pasting the code.  It's not necessary to show any screenshots of code.  It would have been more helpful to indicate what line 38 is, where the error message was telling you the problem exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that the error is on line 38.  Since you didn't say which line that is, I'm going to guess that it's on this one:

```
    const data = snapshot.data()
```

According to the [API docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/DocumentSnapshot#data), data() returns `DocumentData or undefined`, where `undefined` indicates no document was found.  In TypeScript, this means your code needs to show that it's prepared to handle `undefined` in order to access properties on the returned object.  You're not doing that here.  As you suggested, you need to use a conditional to determine if the document exists:

```
const data = snapshot.data()
if (data) {
    return admin.firestore().doc('posts/{postID}').update({postCommentsTot: data.postCommentsTot + 1});
}
else {
    return null
}
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, that works so far. But then I get a new error. It appears at the `.then(snapshot => {` line, saying `Argument of type '(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot) => Promise<WriteResult> | null' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: DocumentSnapshot) => WriteResult | PromiseLike<WriteResult>'.
  Type 'Promise<WriteResult> | null' is not assignable to type 'WriteResult | PromiseLike<WriteResult>'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'WriteResult | PromiseLike<WriteResult>'.`

Comment: You also need to return a promise that's resolved when all the async work is complete.  `return admin.firestore()...`

Comment: Is `if(data) {...} else {return admin.firestore().doc(docPath).update({})}` a good solution? Because it always logs an info statement in the firebase console. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Every successful function invocation always logs two info lines. I don't think you can avoid that.